# Binding a sequence of events using the FOR loop

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hai. I am trying to bind a sequence of events to several divs using javascript jQuery library. Here is what I am trying to do.

There will be many div's on the screen with id's div1 div2 div3 ... div10 and so on. However only the  first div with id 'div1' will be dispalyed with all the other div's hidden. When the user hovers over div1, div2 should be shown and when he hovers over div 2, div 3 should be shown and this should continue sequently till the last div.

I av managed to come up with a solution using jQueries next method.

```
$('div').each(function(){
    $(this).mouseover(function(){
        $(this).next().show();
    });
});
```

However since i am newly learning javascript i wanted to redo it using a FOR loop and it wont work.

```
for (var i=1; i<11; i++){
    $('#div' + i).mouseover(function(){
        $('#div' + (i+1)).show();
    });
}
```

After a bit of playing around, i figured that since i am creating a new function the value of 'i' gets interpreted only when the function is being executed and not when the function is being created. Can someone please explain to me how to avoid this pit fall and achieve what i av done with the jQuery.next() using javascripts FOR loop. Thanks.

Comment: why did you change your call? $(this).next().show(); will still work in that for loop

Comment: @corroded i wanted to avoid .next() and find an alternate solution

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is that there only one variable `i` for all divs, and its value at the end on the for loop will be 11. What you can do is something like

```
for (var i=1; i<11; i++){
    $('#div' + i).mouseover(function(){
        var index_string = $(this).attr('id').substring(3), //return, say the string '6'
            index = parseInt(index_string, 10); //convert it to a number
        $('#div' + (index+1)).show();
    });
}
```

A more sophisticated approach, using anonymous functions to store the indices:

```
for (var i=1; i<11; i++){
    (function() {
        var j = i;
        $('#div' + j).mouseover(function(){
            $('#div' + (j+1)).show();
        });
    })();
}
```

Comment: Exactly. @Shafee - in your original for loop the function bound to the mouseover will file long after the loop has finished. At that point i will indeed be 11. Better to stick with jQuery each in this instance.

Answer (score 3):

When you write something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++){
    $('#div' + i).mouseover(function () {
        $('#div' + (i+1)).show();
    });
}
```

you create a closure over the `i` variable in every 10 function that you create, but there is only one copy of the `i` variable and all of the functions see the same value (11 in this case because that was the value that ended the loop). It effect you have every mouseover handler trying to show '#div12' which as I assume doesn't exist.

It could work if you used something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 11; i++) {
    (function (j) {
        $('#div' + i).mouseover(function () {
            $('#div' + (j+1)).show();
        });
    }(i));
}
```

In this example you would create a new variable `j` in every iteration (by creating and immediately calling a new function with argument `j` that would take a value of `i` in that iteration) and so every one of your event handlers could have its own version with correct value.

I am saying it only to explain what is going on because other people have already given better solutions.

Answer (score 2):

```
for (var i=1; i<4; i++){
        (function(j){
            $('#div' + j).mouseover(function(){           
            $(this).next().show();
            })
        }(i));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

if you don't need (this) object you can do the following:

```
for (var i=1; i<11; i++){
    $('#div').mouseover(function(j, e){
        $('#div' + (j+1)).show();
    }.bind(null, i));
}
```

and if you still need (this) object do

```
for (var i=1; i<11; i++){
    $('#div').mouseover(function(j, e){
        $('#div' + (j+1)).show();
    }.bind($('#div'), i));
}
```